# Apache rewrite .php and everything after

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

## To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]
```

the above works as far as removing `.php` from all of my urls. is it possible though to remove all parameters after the url if they exist? for example, rewrite `site.com/index.php?id=24` to `site.com/index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `?` after the %1:

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R,L,NC]
# here ---------^
```

When there is a `?` in the target URI of a rewrite rule, the rule won't append the query string unless there's a `QSA` flag.

Comment: Where/how would I append the QSA flag? I am newish to this.

Comment: @Norse inside the square brackets where all the flags go. But you don't want it because you *don't* want to append the query string

Comment: What if I wanted to pass GET parameters, doesn't that involve the QSA flag?

Comment: @Norse if you *want* the GET parameters, then you don't want the `?` at all. I assumed you wanted to get rid of them. If you want only certain GET parameters to get passed along, then you need to match against `%{QUERY_STRING}`